# This code is showing a error with poping a window "debug assertion failed "

Tags: c++, string

**So this code poped with a error window during runtime  saying that debug assertion failed and string subscript out of range?**

```
//aim of this code is to convert a string to its reversed ::: sample input yeah ::: output haey 
#include<iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
   string word;
   string converted;

   cin >> word;
   int size = word.size();
   for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
       converted[i] = word[size - i-1];
   }
   cout << converted;

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: `sizeof(word) / sizeof(char)` doesn't do what you think it does. Just do `word.size()`.

Comment: ok, i replaced that statement with word.size();    So, there is still same results / error !

Comment: There was another problem that I missed. See my edited answer.

Comment: @AadityaGarg please edit your question with the additional info you posted in comments, and upvote the answer if it was useful to you.

Comment: @BessieTheCow Sorry ! i cant upvote as my account reputation is less than 15

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::string` are different from plain char arrays. They store extra stuff such as the length of the string, and sometimes the actual string is stored separately. Therefore, `sizeof(word)` isn't going to give you the correct length of the string.

Simply use `word.size()` to get the length of the string.

Also, your string `converted` doesn't contain any characters, so `converted[i]` is accessing an invalid index. One way to fix this is to add the new characters to the end of the string in your loop, by doing `converted += word[size - i - 1]`.

Comment: but i have a further query this is working smooth But , what's the reason that previous one was not working i.e converted[0]=word[3]  in case input:::yeah and loop proceed further

Comment: @AadityaGarg `converted[0]` is trying to access the character at index 0, but strings are empty by default so no such character exists.